# Can I change the icon showed in notification when I plug in an earphone?

Tags: notification, volume-control

When I plug in earphone, volume notify was showed on desktop, I want the icon change to earphone style icon, so i can sure the earphone is ready(recognized by system).

Maybe it is Indicator Applications matter, for I think here is not a stock icon for earphone. Only some volume png are found in /usr/share/icons/gnome/. So all linux system never need an stock earphone icon?